# HTML/CSS Navigation Bar Won't Reach Edge

Tags: html, css

New to CSS/HTML and ive been trying to create a navigation bar for a website project. However, I can't seem to get the navigation bar to reach the top/left/right edges. What am I doing wrong?

```css
ul.header {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  Padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:rgb(97, 23, 214);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;

}

li {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none
}

li.header {
  float: left;

}

li.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=shell.css>
  </head>
<body>
  <ul class="header">
    <li class="header">Home</li>   
    <li class="header">About Me</li>
    <li class="header">Contact Me</li>
    <li class="right">JAIME<b>MONCAYO</b></li>
  </ul>    
  <h1> Lorem forem dorem amaculi laculi </h1> 
    <p class="header"> loret foret goret horet aboret </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you setting the margin of `body` to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`head` tag should only have scripts and styles. It cannot have `ul` or any other HMTL tags. Below is the updated code for you:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.header {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  Padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(97, 23, 214);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

li {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none
}

li.header {
  float: left;
}

li.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul class="header">
  <li class="header">Home</li>
  <li class="header">About Me</li>
  <li class="header">Contact Me</li>
  <li class="right">JAIME<b>MONCAYO</b></li>
</ul>
<h1> Lorem forem dorem amaculi laculi </H1>
<p class="header"> loret foret goret horet aboret </p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and advice on the HTML portion I really appreciate it and this solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

The browser adds some css which has to be reset. Best to use Twitter Bootstrap for the purpose, but that will introduce some complexity.

So for the time being just this piece of CSS code will do.

```
body {
 margin:0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your CSS.

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
ul.header {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    Padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:rgb(97, 23, 214);
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;

}

li {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none
}

li.header {
    float: left;

}

li.right {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=shell.css>
<ul class="header">
<li class="header">Home</li>   
<li class="header">About Me</li>
<li class="header">Contact Me</li>
<li class="right">JAIME<b>MONCAYO</b></li>
</ul>    
    <h1> Lorem forem dorem amaculi laculi </H1> 
</head>
<body>
<p class="header"> loret foret goret horet aboret </p>
</body>
</html>
```

It's gonna remove all the paddings and margins your HTML tags

Answer (score 1):

The `body` tag has always a default style which gave him `margin: 8px;` this is what preventing you from reaching the edges, to solve it reset the body to `margin: 0`

```css
/* Resetting the body margin */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul.header {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  Padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:rgb(97, 23, 214);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

li {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none
}

li.header {
  float: left;

}

li.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=shell.css>
  </head>
<body>
  <ul class="header">
    <li class="header">Home</li>   
    <li class="header">About Me</li>
    <li class="header">Contact Me</li>
    <li class="right">JAIME<b>MONCAYO</b></li>
  </ul>    
  <h1> Lorem forem dorem amaculi laculi </h1> 
    <p class="header"> loret foret goret horet aboret </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix up the `head` and `header`. Your `ul` should be within the body tag.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=shell.css>

<h1> Lorem forem dorem amaculi laculi </H1> 
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="header">
       <li class="header">Home</li>   
       <li class="header">About Me</li>
       <li class="header">Contact Me</li>
       <li class="right">JAIME<b>MONCAYO</b></li>
    </ul>    
    <p class="header"> loret foret goret horet aboret </p>
</body>
</html>
```